# Magento and innodb_buffer_pool_size =2G when Data is only 500M

Tags: magento, innodb

Magento white-paper recommends innodb_buffer_pool_size be set at 50% to 80% of my servers 4G ram.
Is this really necessary when my Magento database has only 500M table data and 500M Indexes ?

I know other variables need to be considered, but setting innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G seams a bit excessive...! I'm i correct?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

"This of course assumes your database is large so you need large buffer pool, if not – setting buffer pool a bit larger than your database size will be enough."

so basically yeah, if your innodb data(tables,indexes,etc.)  are far less than 2G, you aren't gaining performance with the higher setting.

Answer (score 0):

nope, this suggestion is not dependent of the size of your dataset but rather tied to performance and resources available for innodb to perform faster/best